# How can change route in React 18?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

In the past I use `withRouter` Higher Order Component (HOC) and `props.history.push()` function to use for handle route.

But in React 18, these are not available.

I want to edit a post and redirect home page. I use `Link` in home page to go edit page. To get post id, I use `useParams()` hook, but after edit completed, redirect is a problem.

```js
const handleSubmit = useCallback((e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  Axios.put("/api/posts/" + id, state)
    .then(() => {
      // redirect
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}, [id, state])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`useNavigate`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate) hook to access the `navigate` function. Use `navigate(to, { replace: true })` to issue a REPLACE navigation action, e.g. a "redirect".

Example:

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const navigate = useNavigate();

const handleSubmit = useCallback((e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  Axios.put("/api/posts/" + id, state)
    .then(() => {
      navigate(/* target path */, { replace: true });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}, [id, state, navigate]);

...
```

For more information on other changes from RRD v5 to v6 you might want to review the [Upgrading from v5](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5) guide.